# Why drilling too slow is bad?

Tags: drill

Recently I was watching some YouTube machinist channels, where for a few times I've heard phrases like "you need higher speed when you use carbide bits".

I understand why operating drill or lathe too fast would have consequences, like overheating for example, but what are the drawbacks of running too slow?

Comment: Each type and size of bit will have different correct speed depending on the materiel.  Drilling at too slow/low speed will usually make the job take longer and maybe the chips will not clear out fast enough, clogging the flutes.

Comment: the harder the material the slower the speed, same applies to drill size. there are no consequences drilling too slow.

Comment: how ever you need the right speed to achieve smooth  cut

Comment: Too slow and you're work-hardening the metal you're trying to cut.  Feeds and speeds.

Comment: I seem to remember that a larger diameter hole does better at a slower speed.

Comment: Every cutting edge has a suitable linear cutting speed defined for the given material and heat treatment - no good guessing.